# What table does Drupal store its content

Tags: php, drupal

We have a website running Drupal. Our API to which our website will pass information to will get content articles from specific tables We need to know what table/ tables the content articles are stored.

Answer (score 1):

Open PhpMyAdmin and check it out. Basic table is "node", but for every additional field you create in your content type Drupal creates new table(s).

My advice is not to write custom queriess but to use `Views` module (and some of it's submodule, i.e. `Views data export`) to get data and create export feed - would make your life much easier. Or use some specialized module for generating feeds, like...hmmm `Feeds`.

https://www.drupal.org/project/views

https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export

https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on what fields your articles have.

The node id and its most basic information is saved in the node (nid, title, status,created,changed, type and user)

Then every field you add will create a new table for it's data so for example
if you have the fields with the machine names subtitle and website you will need to join the tables "field_data_field_subtitle" and field_data_field_website".

If you that keep in mind that each field can have its own fields for data for example if the website field is an url field it will have field_website_url and field_website_title and feild_website_attributes to contain the data for that field.

Furthermore fields like references to taxonomies will only contain a target_id so you will need to join the taxonomy table as well.

Of course the question is why do you want to do custom queries (which i advice not to) i advice you to look into [EntityFieldQuery](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/howtos/how-to-use-entityfieldquery-for-drupal-7) in which you don't have to figure out what tabels to join. Or take a look at the [views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) in which you can click together what fields you want and views takes care of your joins.